# Recommended Modelling Technique for Influencer Marketing Scenario

Tags: training, natural-language-processing, sentiment-analysis

I have an approximately 90,000 row dataset that has information of social media profiles which has columns for biography, follower count, language spoken, name, username and the **label (to identify whether the profile is that of an influencer, brand or news and media)**.

Task: I have to train a model that predicts the label. I then need to produce a confidence interval for each prediction.

As I have never come across a problem like this, I am just after some suggestions of what models I should be using for a situation like this? I am thinking Natural Language Processing (NLP), but not sure.

Also, for NLP (if a suitable method), any codes or advice to help me implement for the first time on Python would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends very much on the structure of the data.

I would think about feature extraction first, which could be certain words occurring in the bio, and a class of user name ('real' name, numerical id, etc). Once you have a set of features for each data item, turn them into a list of feature vectors.

Then run them through a number of machine learning algorithms. This is where the shape of the data matters, as some algorithms will work better than others. I would try eg decision trees (ID3), which are very efficient once trained (but they don't give you a confidence interval). But any other ML algorithm might work. They will all have trade-offs with speed of training, memory requirements, and speed of classification; some will give you a class-label probability, others will just give you one label.

The best way would be to use a sample, and identify which algorithm works well and fits your specific requirements. Then use that for the full data set.

Alternatively you could just use, for example, the [Stanford ML classifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier). That will give you a confidence interval, and will probably work reasonably well.

Comment: Thank you so much Oliver - this is really helpful. I will try and implement as you have said

Comment: Note that selecting the right features might have a bigger impact on the outcome than the actual ML algorithm, so it's worth trying out several alternatives there as well.